# Create nested menu with keyboard navigation

Tags: reactjs

I want to create a Menu with nested nodes and keyboard navigation.
But how can I get the correct Node component on KeyDown event?

React Docs marks Children and cloneElement as not recommended (deprecated in future?).

https://react.dev/reference/react/legacy

So I tried to store all nodes in an array using context. I tried to just update the last active and the next active node to keep rerendering minimal. But how can I figure out the relation between nodes? How to know which node is a sibling to the activeNode? How to get the tree of the nodes?

Is there a way to access the ReactTree? Or any other ideas?

```
let MenuContext = createContext();
function Menu(){
  let nodes = useRef([]);
  let activeNode = useRef(null);

  function add(dispatch){
    nodes.push(dispatch);
  }

  function remove(dispatch){
    nodes.slice(nodes.find(item => item === dispatch), 1);
  }

  function handleKeyDown(e){
    if(e.key === "ArrowDown"){ // or ArrowUp, ArrowLeft, ArrowRight, etc.
      // How to find childNode, prevSiblingNode, nextSiblingNode, parentNode
      let nextActive = nodes.find( node => /* TODO */);
      if(nextActive){
        activeNode.current(false); 
        nextActive(true);
        activeNode.current = nextActive;
      }
  }

  return <ul tabindex="0" onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}>
    <MenuContext.Provider value={add, remove, activeNode}>c{children}</MenuContext.Provider>
  </ul>
}

function Node({label, children}){
  let ctx = useContext(MenuContext);
  let [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    if(!ctx) return;
    ctx.add(setActive);
    return () => ctx.remove(setActive);
  });
  return <li>
    <span className={active && "Node__active"}>{label}</span>
    {children}
  </li>
}

function App(){
  return <Menu>
    <Node label="Node1"/>
    <Node label="Node2">
      <ul>
        <Node label="Node2.1" />
        <Node label="Node2.2" />
      </ul>
    </Node>
  </Menu>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make your node layout follow some sort of data structure i.e. put it in an array and use `Array.map()` in the `Menu` function to generate it. Then you can put your listener in `Menu` and just use state to keep track of which index is selected. The nested part makes this marginally more difficult, but honestly it shouldn't be that hard. I'm not going to attempt to implement that here, because it really depends on your desired behavior (should it automatically enter child nodes, or keep going through the root until another action is made).

```js
const layout = [
  {
    label: 'Node1',
  },
  {
    label: 'Node2',
    children: [
      {
        label: 'Node2.1'
      },
      {
        label: 'Node2.2'
      },
    ],
  },
];


function Node({ selected, nodeData }) {
  return (
    <li>
      <span className={selected && "Node__active"}>{nodeData.label}</span>
      {nodeData.children && (
        nodeData.children.map((nodeData, index) => {
          return (
            <Node
              key={nodeData.label}
              selected={index === selectedIndex}
              nodeData={nodeData}
            />
          )
        })
      )}
    </li>
  )
}

function Menu() {
  const [nodes, setNodes] = useState(layout);
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);

  const handleKeyDown = (evt) => {
    switch (evt.key) {
      case 'ArrowDown':
        setSelectedIndex(selectedIndex + 1);
        break;
      case 'ArrowUp':
        setSelectedIndex(Math.max(selectedIndex - 1, 0));
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }

  return (
    <ul tabindex="0" onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}>
      {nodes.map((nodeData, index) => {
        return (
          <Node
            key={nodeData.label}
            selected={index === selectedIndex}
            nodeData={nodeData}
          />
        )
      })}
    </ul>
  )
}
```